# Docker Container with internal and host network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I'm pretty new to Docker so I might use terms not correctly - and so didn't use Google with the right words... Please excuse!

I have several Docker containers for home automation that are all being configured with a docker-compose.yml.
Internally they all communicate via the virtual network (172.xxx.xxx.xxx) that Docker creates through the yml file.

```
networks:
    homeautomation-network:
        driver: bridge
```

Now I want one specific container to be **also** connected to the network my host is in (192.168.xxx.xxx/24).
With this config it communicates internally:

```
    iobroker:
        restart: always
        image: buanet/iobroker:latest
        container_name: iobroker
        hostname: iobroker
        ports:
          - "8081:8081"
        networks:
          - homeautomation-network
        volumes:
          - ./iobroker:/opt/iobroker
```

What would I need to change, that this container can reach both networks, the virtual and the "real" one?

Comment: You shouldn't need to change anything: the container should be able to make outbound calls without special setup, and it can receive inbound connections on the host's IP address and the first `ports:` number.  Is there a specific problem you're having, and specific application source code you can share?

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing to share, no code or whatsoever involved. The problem is: As soon as I run ioBroker in a Docker container with a bridged network and no dedicated connection to the "outside" world it won't find my HUE Bridge etc. - everything that is reachable via IP and Auto-Discovery.
When I run ioBroker "natively" (not in a container) it finds all the devices instantly. So I was assuming I need to make some kind of dedicated connection to my host network. Like having a (virtual) second network card for the container that is connected to my host network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this question is quite old, I`ll try to answer it, as this comes along from time to time and the topic is not yet outdated... :)

Add a MACVLAN to your ioBroker container to give it a seperate ip address and full access to your network.

The networks definition should look something like this:

```
networks:
  homeautomation-network:
    driver: bridge
  macvlan-network:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: eth0 #depends of your Docker host
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.xxx.xxx/24
          gateway: 192.168.xxx.xxx
          ip_range: 192.168.xxx.xxx/xx
```

To add this network to your ioBroker docker container it should look like this:

```
iobroker:
  restart: always
  image: buanet/iobroker:latest
  container_name: iobroker
  hostname: iobroker
#  ports:
#    - "8081:8081" #no longer needed
  networks:
    homeautomation-network:
    macvlan-network:
      ipv4_address: 192.168.xxx.xxx #optional to specify an ip address
  volumes:
    - ./iobroker:/opt/iobroker
```

Make sure to read and understand about what's a MACVLAN at the [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/macvlan/). You also have to find out the network device (parent) of your Docker host you want to attach the MACVLAN and define an ip range for it.

For further support related to ioBroker (with or without Docker) join the [ioBroker Community](https://forum.iobroker.net/).

Regards,
André (buanet)